# How to update firebase document and reflect changes in UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: swift, firebase, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

So in my app I am displaying images and videos in a scrollable format. I am using UICollectionView Cells to display them. Then on top of each cell I built a SwiftUI view to display things like the like button and other user interaction buttons. The issue I'm running into is I need to update the likesCount field of a post without reloading the whole cell. My listener is defined in my UIViewController:

```
func listenForPosts() {
    listener = databasecollection.order(by: "date", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        var itemsAdded = [IndexPath]()
        var itemsModified = [IndexPath]()
        
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { difference in
            let data = difference.document.data()
            let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
            let username = data["username"] as? String ?? ""
            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let caption = data["caption"] as? String ?? ""
            let profilepic = data["profilepic"] as? String ?? ""
            let url = data["url"] as? String ?? ""
            let location = data["location"] as? String ?? ""
            let postType = data["postType"] as? String ?? ""
            let date = data["date"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
            let posterId = data["posterId"] as? String ?? ""
            let numLikes = data["numLikes"] as? Int ?? 0
            
            let post = PostItem(id: id, username: username, name: name, caption: caption, profilepic: profilepic, url: url, location: location, postType: postType, date: date, posterId: posterId, numLikes: numLikes)
            
            if difference.type == .added {
                self?.feedPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
                itemsAdded.append(IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
            }
            else if difference.type == .modified {
                if let index = self?.feedPosts.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == post.id }) {
                    self?.feedPosts[index] = post
                    itemsModified.append(IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))
                }
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: itemsAdded)
                self?.collectionView.reloadItems(at: itemsModified)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to separate the LikeButtonView in the SwiftUI view that goes on top of each cell, but then I realized the primary issue, especially because the videos keep restarting when I press the like button, is that the like count needs to update and be reflected in the ui, but I can't reload an entire cell because I'm updating the like count of a post.